# fast way to replace the small enough value with zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have created a multi-dimensional array, whose information is shown as follows.

It can be seen that there a lot of values that are quite small. In fact, they all should be equal to zero. Are there any quick ways, to replace those very small values (e.g., <=e-10) with 0.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the [round method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_round.htm) with the following parameters:

```
arr[j][i] = round(arr[j][i], 10)
```

to round to 10 digits (e^-10)

[numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) also has a method for this as well to round the whole array

```
numpy.around(arr,10,arr)
```

Comment: This will affect _all_ the data, not only the small samples.

Comment: It looks like I possibly misinterpreted what they wanted, but it also looks like it was the answer that they were looking for though because the answer was accepted.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with

```
 data[data<threshold] = 0
```